# Adding left and right margins to a table view inside UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I am having a UITableViewController subclass and want to add left and right edge margins to the tableview. I tried below but that is not helping. I do not want to change the view hierarchy by moving tableview as subview to a UIView.

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 20.0, 0.0, 20.0)
```

What can be done in this case?

Comment: Have you tried just doing this with constraints?

Comment: I tried but since table view is the top most view, I am not able to add left and right margins.

Comment: Have you tried setting the width equal to tableview? 0.95 (play around with the margin)

Answer (score 0):

After some testing myself I think your best options is to `customise` your `TableViewCells` and add a `margin` property there. By doing so, you can easily change the margin `dynamically` or set it to `0` if you want to remove it completely.

For inspiration check out the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31769708/adding-margin-to-uitableviewcell) by [@ezcoding](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1149780/ezcoding). Hope this helps.